# Format GeoJson based on IEnumerable<Users>

Tags: c#, .net, api, ienumerable, geojson

I have a basic API running, I can store data and get the data as usual. However, I am having issues with formatting my content. I can get a list of all my users with HTTPGet, and it looks like this...

```
[
    {
        "userId": "1                           ",
        "geoHash": "123456789",
        "latitude": 1.234,
        "longitude": 5.689,
        "locationDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00"

    },
    {
        "userId": "2                           ",
        "geoHash": "123456789",
        "latitude": 1.234,
        "longitude": 5.689,
    "locationDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00"

    },
    {
        "userId": "3                           ",
        "geoHash": "123456789",
        "latitude": 1.234,
        "longitude": 5.689,
    "locationDate": "2019-07-01T00:00:00"

    }
]
```

However, I have no clue to how I can turn this into a GeoJson (https://geojson.org/) which looks like this...

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}
```

And this is the basic of how I get my user list

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Users> GetUsers()
        {
            return _context.Users;
        }
```

I've been searching for hours and the content around this subject seems to be somewhat confusing for me, I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Do you want to return a [FeatureCollection](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#page-12) of all the users?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Not sure if you can cast an array into "coordinates"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: although the question contains the user data as Json, comments now indicate it is contained in an `IEnumerable<Users>`. The code below assumes the property names of those values are the same as shown in the Json.*

You need to 'project' the user data as GeoJson, the easiest way is to use an anonymous type then serialize it: this creates valid GeoJson according to [this linter](http://geojsonlint.com/).

```cs
    var users = GetUsers();

    var userGeo = users.Select(u => new
        {
            type = "Feature",
            geometry = new
            {
                type = "Point",
                coordinates = new double[] { u.longitude, u.latitude }
            },
            properties = new {
                name = "User " + u.userId.Trim()
            }
        }
    );

    var featureCollection = new {
        type = "FeatureCollection",
        features = userGeo
    };

    var geoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(featureCollection, Formatting.Indented);
```

Output:

```js
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          5.689,
          1.234
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "User 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          5.689,
          1.234
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "User 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          5.689,
          1.234
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "User 3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: With the risk of sounding extremely stupid, how can I put my json into a string within public IEnumerable<Users> GetUsers()?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In your question you had the user data as Json, so I deserialized them as user objects. If they're **already** users, then you don't need to do that.

Comment: Of course, sorry for not clarifying it, that is the output I get when I call my get method. My question is, how do I take my "return _context.Users;" as a string so it can be used by your code here var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(MyString/return);

Comment: Still confused. If `GetUsers()` returns an `IEnumerable<Users>` you can just call the projection on that..?

Comment: string json = GetUsers().ToString();
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Users>>(json);

This gives me...
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: M. Path '', line 0, position 0.'
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[Projects.Models.Users]"

Comment: I just don't see why you're trying to turn your user entities into Json just to deserialize them again? If you really want to, then call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetUsers);` - ` GetUsers().ToString()` will return the type of the return value.

Comment: That made it work, however, im not able to return it. Sorry for the confusion again, im pretty new at this. I am able to capture it on a breakpoint but not able to return the raw string in geoJson.  Like so return geoJson;

Comment: Btw, forgot to mention it but your salutation worked great. So Thank you! Got everything hooked up and also have better understanding on how things works.